# Yii afterAjaxUpdate happening 13 times?

Tags: ajax, yii, cgridview

in my CGridView I have this simple function:

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' =>
'function(id, data) {
    var checks2 = $("#checks").val().split(",").sort();
    $("#rule-competitors-grid input:checkbox").each(function() {
        console.log($.inArray($(this).attr("name").substr(11,$(this).attr("name").length - 12), checks2));
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr("name").substr(11,$(this).attr("name").length - 12), checks2) !== -1)
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
}',
```

On a list that shows 2 items at a time (for debugging).

See the `console.log()`s over there? They happen 13 times each call.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How many competitors you have in your grid? 13? You are doing a .each function there so for each row having input:checkbox you are logging.

Comment: If I had 13 there would be some sort of correlation and I'd imagine it gets run for each checkbox. Problem is it's not the iteration that's running too much, it's the entire function. I have 2 checkboxes, and what I have is 13 iterations through 2 checkboxes every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was dumb and unrelated, but I'm sure someone in this world might encounter the same.

My problem was that the JavaScript was loaded through AJAX in the loaded page in a dialog/tab and not in the main page. What happens is that the "click" trigger was re-assigned, and *added* to the elements every time I reloaded the tab/dialog. After reloading it 13 times to check on small changes (since it's an AJAX dialog I was able to avoid having to update the whole page), it was loaded inside.

To avoid this, either unbind the events as soon as the dialog/tab is reloaded, or use `.on()` to lively load it on the main page and not the tab/dialog so the code isn't re-added to the event every time you load it.

Answer (score 1):

*Problem:*

Your CSS selector is valid for 13 checkboxes which you then iterate in your "each" statement. You'll need a new approach if you are looking to update one specific row at a time.

Yii's documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) says it all:

A javascript function that will be invoked after a successful AJAX response is received. The function signature is function(id, data) where 'id' refers to the ID of the **grid view**, 'data' the received **ajax response data**.

---

*Suggestion:*

Change your selector to find the exact checkbox you need to update based on a classname and ID value. Work from the grid's 'id' variable down to the specific row you want to make changes to.

Comment: I have an array of IDs, and I iterate through the checkboxes to see if they're in that array. Then I want them checked. What's funny about the number 13 is, that I only have 2 checkboxes at the time of checking this and I'm trying to run it once per pagination.